# How to display two gvis gauge meters side by side using Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I am working on shiny app where in I'm trying to display the baseline and model accuracy using `gvisGauge`.

I have been successful in displaying them in separate tabpanels and also in the same tabpanel one below the other.

But I want to show them side by side i.e in horizontal alignment in the same tab. How can I achieve this? Tried searching for options, but couldn't get any.

As of now, my sample code is as below

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Guage'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('n1', 'Enter your Base Accuracy', 40, 0.5, 100),


      numericInput('n2', 'Enter your Model Accuracy', 40, 0.5, 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Accuracy Guage",htmlOutput("view1"),htmlOutput("view2"))
    )
  )
)))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$view1 <- renderGvis({
    df1 <- data.frame(Label = "Base Accuracy", Value = input$n1)
    gvisGauge(df1,
              options=list(min=0, max=100, greenFrom=90,
                           greenTo=100, yellowFrom=75, yellowTo=89.99,
                           redFrom=0, redTo=74.99, width=300, height=300));  

})

output$view2 <- renderGvis({
  df2 <- data.frame(Label = "Model Accuracy", Value = input$n2)
  gvisGauge(df2,
            options=list(min=0, max=100, greenFrom=90,
                         greenTo=100, yellowFrom=75, yellowTo=89.99,
                         redFrom=0, redTo=74.99, width=300, height=300));  

})


})
```

Comment: I made some edits, but I can only guess at your code. Code you make sure that your code excerpts are accurate, that comments are comments, etc.?

Comment: Gregor,thats not the actual code.I have just given the flow.I'll post the exact reproducible code as requested for more understanding.

Comment: Edited it with actual code,could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column to specify the layout or you can use `div` and go with `tags$style` and use `display:inline-block`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

ui =(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Guage'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('n1', 'Enter your Base Accuracy', 40, 0.5, 100),


      numericInput('n2', 'Enter your Model Accuracy', 40, 0.5, 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Accuracy Guage",
                 column(4,htmlOutput("view1")),
                 column(4,htmlOutput("view2"))
      )
    )
  ))))
server = function(input, output) {

  output$view1 <- renderGvis({
    df1 <- data.frame(Label = "Base Accuracy", Value = input$n1)
    gvisGauge(df1,
              options=list(min=0, max=100, greenFrom=90,
                           greenTo=100, yellowFrom=75, yellowTo=89.99,
                           redFrom=0, redTo=74.99, width=300, height=300));  

  })

  output$view2 <- renderGvis({
    df2 <- data.frame(Label = "Model Accuracy", Value = input$n2)
    gvisGauge(df2,
              options=list(min=0, max=100, greenFrom=90,
                           greenTo=100, yellowFrom=75, yellowTo=89.99,
                           redFrom=0, redTo=74.99, width=300, height=300));  

  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```